# Why have my wither skeletons stopped spawning on Xbox?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I recently went into the nether and found loads and loads of wither skeletons spawning,  but after I killed them all they stopped spawning altogether. Why is this? This is occurring in the Xbox One version.

Comment: Wither skeletons are fairly uncommon, how long has it been since you killed the last one?

Comment: Have you left the area/the nether entirely and jumped back in?

Comment: there were absolutely loads and now there is none, its been like 3 hours

Comment: @ben and yes ben

Comment: I've even tried turning off my console fully, no luck.

Answer (score 1):

There are three (3) [requirements for a Wither Skeleton to spawn](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Wither_Skeleton#Spawning):

- Light levels must be 7 or less
- Must be on Nether Fortress (on nether bricks and their variants)
- Must have 3 blocks of vertical space (wither skeletons are 2.5 blocks tall)

In other words, be sure to hang around dark Nether Fortress with plenty of head room.

Answer (score 0):

You'll just have to reset your nether to get the wither skeletons to spawn again, I find once you've entered the nether, left, and came back they stop spawning. I'm on my seventh beacon and I've had to reset the nether who knows how many times.